# How to read a dutch char ë stored as question mark(?) in database using c# or in SQL query?

Tags: character-encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

Data is already stored in database(Oracle and SQL server both) so i don't need to insert it using N in beginning. I am using SQL Developer to see the result but I can see only Question mark not the actual character. I tried all settings for nls parameters and different font but no luck. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

2 things to double check

1) "Tools" -> "Preferences" -> "Environment" -> "Encoding" is set to UTF8

and that the tools is using a font that has that character

2) "Tools" -> "Preferences" ->"Code Editor" -> "Fonts"

Answer (score -1):

```
charset=UTF-8
```

If it is already set to UTF-8 then take a look at the font that is selected.